# ServiceStack Wrapper for Bloomberg OpenFIGI

Tags: servicestack

I need to make the following call to an open API (https://www.openfigi.com/api)

Curl Example:

```
curl -v -X POST 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping'   \
     --header 'Content-Type: text/json'             \
     --data '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]'
```

Request Format
The request is passed in via HTTP request body. The only supported HTTP verb is POST. Here is a sample request to the API:

```
[
  {"idType":"ID_ISIN","idValue":"US4592001014"},
  {"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"},
  {"idType":"ID_BB_UNIQUE","idValue":"EQ0010080100001000","currency": "USD"},
  {"idType":"ID_SEDOL","idValue":"2005973","micCode":"EDGX", "currency":"USD"}
]
```

Using ServiceStack Request DTO, how do I make a RequestDto to achieve a call to  to the above third party service endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an exercise of creating DTOs which match the shape of the JSON you want to output and JSON you want to receive. To emit the exact the exact JSON property names you can either use `[DataMember]` on the Request DTO, or `JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true` to tell ServiceStack to serialize properties in camelCase or you can use [JsConfig.With() to create a Custom Scope](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#custom-config-scopes).

I've created a [Live example of this in Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=acbf6173444b7dba1556ac9a842defd6&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) which you can use to experiment against Bloomberg's API.

I've used `[DataMember]` attribute here as it will work independent of your Json Serialization config. You don't need to do this for the Response DTO because ServiceStack Serializers is case-insensitive.

So to send the Request that matches the shape of that JSON you can use:

```
[DataContract]
public class Mapping
{
    [DataMember(Name="idType")]
    public string IdType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="idValue")]
    public string IdValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="exchCode")]
    public string ExchCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="micCode")]
    public string MicCode { get; set; }
}
```

You can use ServiceStack's [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) to easily send requests to 3rd Party APIs, e.g:

```
var url = "https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping";

var json = url.PostJsonToUrl(new[]{
    new Mapping { IdType = "ID_ISIN", IdValue = "US4592001014" },
    new Mapping { IdType = "ID_WERTPAPIER", IdValue = "851399", ExchCode = "US" },
    new Mapping { IdType = "ID_BB_UNIQUE", IdValue = "EQ0010080100001000", Currency = "USD" },
    new Mapping { IdType = "ID_SEDOL", IdValue = "2005973", MicCode = "EDGX", Currency = "USD" },
});
```

Then to receive the response you need to create DTOs which match the shape of the JSON Response which looks like:

```
public class BloombertResult
{
    public string Figi { get; set; }
    public string SecurityType { get; set; }
    public string MarketSector { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string ExchCode { get; set; }
    public string ShareClassFIGI { get; set; }
    public string CompositeFIGI { get; set; }
    public string SecurityType2 { get; set; }
    public string SecurityDescription { get; set; }
    public string UniqueIdFutOpt { get; set; }
}

public class BloombergResponse
{
    public List<BloombertResult> Data { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can just deserialize into a collection of BloombergResponse, e.g:

```
var response = json.FromJson<BloombergResponse[]>();
```

Gistlyn will show you a nice human readable preview of each variable by clicking on it in the watch window. Or if you're this in a C# Unit test you can quickly see to populated DTOs with:

```
response.PrintDump();
```

Comment: Love the live gistlyn example !

Comment: I would like to add an API-Key header to the Bloomberg post call. ie: 'X-OPENFIGI-APIKEY: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'. How can I achieve this using ServiceStack.

Comment: @MarkH Both [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils#customizing-the-webrequest) and the [C# Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) have request filters which you can use to customize the outgoing request and response filters to parse the HTTP Response.

Comment: Thanks - for anyone else's future reference, I added request filters as follows -> 
url.PostJsonToUrl(request.Mappings, httpReq =>
            {
                httpReq.Headers.Add("X-OPENFIGI-APIKEY", "xxxxx");
            })

Comment: @MarkH This was best asked in a new question as it's not going to be discoverable buried in comments of a different question.